# Android Studio: Sudden Backend Internal Error: Can't inline method call. How do I fix it?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, exception, kotlin

I have a problem. My code was working perfectly fine until one day this Errormessage suddenly appeared during the build `process: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Backend Internal Error: Exception during code generation Cause: Back-end(JVM)Internal Error: Couldn't inline method call "forEach"into public open fun onDataChange`

I've tried updating Android Studio, because somewhere I read that it could be an IDE bug. It didn't help. Thanks in advance for your time :)

```
 private fun addFriend(){

    val addInput = view!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.add_input) as TextView

    val user = fbAuth.currentUser
    val uid = user!!.uid
    val friendCode = addInput.text
    val notificationURL = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"

    //TODO:find user with this friendcode

    if(!friendCode.isEmpty() && friendCode.length == 4) {

        val query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").orderByChild("friendcode").startAt(friendCode.toString()).endAt(friendCode.toString() + "\\uf8ff")
        query.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                //FIRST GET ID OF FRIEND WITH THIS FRIENDCODE
                val children = (dataSnapshot.children)
                children.forEach {
                    val friendId = it.key.toString()
                    if(friendId != uid) {
                        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users")

                        //GET NAME OF FRIEND
                        mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
                            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                                TODO("not implemented")
                            }
                            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                                val friendName = snapshot.child(friendId).child("name").getValue().toString()
                                val friendScore = snapshot.child(friendId).child("score").getValue().toString()
                                val friendToken = snapshot.child(friendId).child("token").child("result").child("token").getValue()
                                val userName = snapshot.child(uid).child("name").getValue().toString()

                                //ADD TO DATABASE
                                mDatabase.child(uid).child("friends").child(friendName).child("id").setValue(friendId)
                                mDatabase.child(uid).child("friends").child(friendName).child("score").setValue(friendScore)


                                }

                                if(activity != null) {
                                    Toast.makeText(activity, "friend added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                }



                            }
                        })

                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(activity,"Friendcode cant be your own",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                // Failed, log a message
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Query error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // ...
            }
        })
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"4-digit Friendcode required",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

> Error message during build: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Backend
>   Internal Error: Exception during code generation Cause:
>   Back-end(JVM)Internal Error: Couldn't inline method call "forEach"into
>   public open fun onDataChange